# Update TabLayout titles

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I've got a `TabLayout` (from the Design Library) that is populated with 2 fragments (that both hold a list of items) through a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

The 2 lists are in connection with each other: They both hold a total of persons and in which list a person is, decides whether he/she is nominated or not. 
You can swipe members from one list to the other and vice versa.

**The problem**

I want/need to show a count (of how many persons are in that particular list) in the tab titles.
Easy enough, I add a bit of code in `getPageTitle` and it works fine. 
Until I change the lists, and I need to tell the `FragmentPagerAdapter` to update its titles again: It won't.

So far, the only solution I found was to call: `mTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(mAdapter);`

All this method does, is `removeAllTabs` and then loop through the ones the `FragmentPagerAdapter` has, adding them as new.

This works for the titles, but isn't very efficient, but most importantly: It forces the first tab to become the selected item again, which isn't a nice experience when swiping from the 2nd tab.

I've tried adding `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(int item)` after the `mTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(mAdapter);` call, but that does not work.

I also tried things like

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
tabLayout.invalidate();
```

With no effect.

Comment: You could try posting the `setCurrentItem()`in a handler or directly to the ViewPager, or if you know the index of the title you want to change use `tabLayout.getTabAt(index)`.

Comment: Wow not sure how I missed that `getTabAt(index) method`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(pos)).view.getTab().setText(title);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how i am doing, I had requirement in which i need to set some count to tab title everytime.

I used custom layout for tab title. here is my custom_tab layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="@dimen/tab_label" />
```

TO setup title **first time** i use my method **setupTabTitle("TAB 1",0);**

```
private void setupTabTitle(String title,int pos) {
   TextView title = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).
          inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
   title .setText(title);
 // set icon
// title .setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite, 0, 0);
   tabLayout.getTabAt(pos).setCustomView(title);
}
```

To update tab-title **next time** i use  tabLayout.getTabAt() object

```
public void updateCustomTabTitle(String title,int pos) {
    TextView tabTitle = (TextView) tabLayout.getTabAt(pos).getCustomView();
    tabTitle.setText(title);
}
```

and this is how i call updateCustomTabTitle method

```
updateCustomTabTitle("My tab title to update",tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition());
```

To get tab-title value

```
public String getCustomTabTitle(int pos) {
    TextView tabOne= (TextView) tabLayout.getTabAt(pos).getCustomView();
    return tabOne.getText().toString();
}
```

**note**: first i tried setupTabTitle method to update tab-title but it does not update title, it append new text at end of title. so i get View from tab-layout and use it to update and read tab value.

Hope this will help you.